# Routing in Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a IoT Hub where I want to route traffic to a Event Hub based on device twin properties. Is this possible or can you only query based on properties on the message itself?

So if I have a device twin property 
"tags":{"customer":"test"}
I would write tags.customer = "test" in the query string field but this does not work.

PS: When I route based on message properties it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing in IoT Hub works **today** only on **message properties**. This reflected in the documentation.

Comment: How can I receive the deviceId of the sender of the telemetric? How can this be done securely as someone could "fake" their deviceId sent with the telemetrics (or as a property)

Comment: Take a look at these threads:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854770/how-does-device-anti-spoofing-work-in-azure-iot-hub
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483084/azure-iot-hub-anti-spoofing

Comment: I added properties as params to the endpoint and I am now able to route traffic from the IoT Hub to an Event Hub.

Comment: As of 2017/08 IOT routing does support message body introspection when using a JSON payload.

Answer (score 1):

As an update it is now possible to do this. Use $twin.tags.customer = 'test'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax#message-routing-query-based-on-message-properties